# Accessing methods from fragment in Android ViewPager

Tags: android

I am quite new to `ViewPager` in android. I successfully implemented the `viewPager` but I can't make some `UI` methods to work properly.

When I am trying to modify some `TextView`'s for example I get `NullPointerException` ( I Know what NullPointer is but I don't understand how to fix it )

I have the following listener of `mPager` :

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                play(position);

                ScreenSlidePagerAdapter fa = (ScreenSlidePagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
                Fragment fragment = fa.getItem(position);

                if (fragment instanceof MusicSliderFragment) {
                    ((MusicSliderFragment) fragment).setSongName(splitName(myDataList.get(position))[0]);
                    ((MusicSliderFragment) fragment).setAuthor(splitName(myDataList.get(position))[1]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

And my `Fragment` is this:

```
public class MusicSliderFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView songName, songAuthor;
    private DiscreteSeekBar seekBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        seekBar = (DiscreteSeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songProgress);
        songName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        songAuthor = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songAuthor);
        songName.setSelected(true);
        songAuthor.setSelected(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setSongName(String name) {
        this.songName.setText(name);
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.songAuthor.setText(author);
    }
}
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

My Adapter Class:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new MusicSliderFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

And my fragment:

```
public class MusicSliderFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView songName, songAuthor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        songName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        songAuthor = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songAuthor);
        songName.setSelected(true);
        songAuthor.setSelected(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setSongName(String name) {
        this.songName.setText(name);
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.songAuthor.setText(author);
    }
}
```

And the ViewPager and adapter are created by the following:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please upload your logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects in adapter class from activity and from that objects you can call any method written in fragment

Comment: So I should call the methods from the `Adapter Class` ?

Comment: yes  as you pass the Two fragment Objects in Adapter constructor and use these two objects if you can show me your activity and adapter i will show you how to  use the objecys

Comment: I have updated my question with the fragment and the adapter from activity, my activity is quite big, what part do you need ?

Comment: adapter class and adapter set to list

Comment: Updated the question with all the informations, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `getItem()` of your adapter. It just return newly instantiated fragment, not the one in your `ViewPager`. You could get the fragment in `ViewPager` by searching it tag using `FragmentManager`.

Instead of using

```
Fragment fragment = fa.getItem(position);
```

Try using this:

```
String tag = "android:switcher:" + mPager.getId()+ ":" + position;
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
MusicSliderFragment fragment
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,MusicSliderFragment fragment) {
            super(fm);
this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }



mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

MusicSliderFragment fragment = new MusicSliderFragment();

        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragment);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

using **"fragment"** object you can call any method of fragment in activity as well as in Adapterclass
```

Comment: This will not use the same fragment over and over ? Shouldn't it be recreated when the swipe is done ?

Comment: it is on your requirement you can reintialize it